# a theorem to simplify continuity in Stewart's calculus: early transcendentals

Tags: calculus

I'm covering section 2.5 of Stewart (on continuity) and stewarts treatment seems needlessly complicated.  It seems like the following theorem would streamline a lot of it:

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions which are continuous at every point in their domains, then each of the following functions is continuous at every point in its domain:

$$1.~~~~~~~ f(x)+g(x)$$
$$2.~~~~~~ f(x)-g(x)$$
$$3.~~~~~~ f(x)g(x)$$
$$4.~~~~~~ c\cdot f(x)$$

$$5. ~~~~~~ f(x)/g(x)$$

$$6.~~~~~~f(g(x)).$$

Is there something pedagogically wrong with giving this theorem?

It seems like it would simplify examples like the ones below because it reduces them to just finding the domain of the function.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the only difference is passing off where the discussion of a restricted domain occurs. Do you want to have that discussion in the context of each example, like Examples 6 and 7 that you shared? Or do you want to have the discussion when introducing the theorem you proposed and (perhaps) attempting to explain a proof of that theorem? If you just want students to "efficiently apply a theorem" from what it says, then surely what you suggest is "faster". But is it *better*, in the sense of student understanding? I'm not so sure.

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan thanks for the feedback. I'm not so sure either. I think I may do them both ways.  I just wanted to be sure I'm not setting some kind of trap for myself down the line.

Comment: No trap, it's all logically equivalent. It's just a matter of whether you want to "do the work" in examples or proofs.

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan Could you write that as an answer?

Comment: I just read this section and there's nothing complicated in it. In (1), the author defines local continuity using limits, in (2) he defines left and right local continuity, in (3) he defines global continuity and (4) is the theorem you wrote about sums, products, etc. of continuous functions.

Comment: @BPP (4) is a *local* version of what I wrote. This global version I find simpler to apply when all functions are continuous.

Comment: @Timkinsella Is (3)+(4) equivalent to your statement?

Comment: @BPP (4) by itself is equivalent, but I'm not teaching an analysis class -- I'm teaching freshman calculus to kids who are probably going to major in finance or accounting.

Comment: also you need (9) for composition

Comment: @TommiBrander: Yes, I would like to write that as an answer, but I don't have a copy of the Stewart text so I can't properly cite everything and place it in context. (Does anyone know how to access this text digitally, or is anyone willing to email me a scan of the relevant pages?)

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan Does Google books contains the relevant passages? https://books.google.no/books?&id=zi3aBAAAQBAJ